# Is this control possible in windows application(Winforms)

Tags: winforms, windows

please check the image below[image]

I would like to know if this kind of control is possible in windows application(Winforms). I tried grid-control but couldn't achieve this.

Basically **Col Name** is populated from database.
Detail Column is not populated from DB,it's column to receive inputs(from text-box & text area)

**Detail** column is must contain multiple line regarding to it's adjacent column(ie. Col Name). as shown in figure above.

Here in the Detail column four sub row are present.but i would like to increase the sub row as per user input say if 6 inputs are to be inputted,2 additional sub row should be generated dynamically.

Basically in a grid view, new row input can be added dynamically. i want something similar like that but in a different context as explained above.

Please let me know if this kinda of control is possible?? if so please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a `DataRepeater` control, which is not part of the normal visual studio controls.  It's in the PowerPack.

See: [DataRepeater Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater.aspx)

To Download: [Microsoft Visual Basic Power Packs 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25169)

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple.
Create a user control for one set (for e.g. ColumnName-A, 4-TextBoxes and 4-TextAreas). Use it for three times.